# T-SQL - Select patients who are readmitted (within some duration) with the same diagnosis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Codes
(
    diagnosis_code CHAR,
    visit_date     DATE,
    visit_id       INT,
    patient_id     int
);
```

I would like to output the `patient_id`s where the patient is readmitted (so a different `visit_id`) with the same `diagnosis_code` within a certain time (say 15 days). For example, if I have the following entries in the table:

```
diagnosis_code visit_date visit_id    patient_id
-------------- ---------- ----------- -----------
A              2018-01-01 1           1
B              2018-01-01 1           1
A              2018-01-07 2           1
C              2018-01-01 3           2
D              2018-01-01 4           3
D              2018-01-20 5           3
E              2018-01-01 6           4
E              2018-01-01 6           4
A              2018-01-07 7           1
```

The query would return only `patient_id` = `1`, and the rationales are as follows:

1. `1`, because between `visit_id` `1` and `2`, this patient shared diagnosis code `A`.
2. **Not** `2` because this patient was only admitted once.
3. **Not** `3` because this patient, although readmitted for the same diagnosis, was not readmitted within 15 days of their initial visit.
4. **Not** `4` because this patient has a duplicated diagnosis code in the same visit.
5. Notice that `patient_id` = `1` is readmitted for the same diagnosis during `visit_id` = `7`, but he was already counted once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a simple join, adding the conditions you described:

```
select
    distinct c.patient_id
  from codes c
  join codes d on d.patient_id = c.patient_id
              and d.visit_id <> c.visit_id
              and d.diagnosis_code = c.diagnosis_code
              and d.visit_date between c.visit_date
                  and dateadd(day, 15, c.visit_date)
```

Comment: I think there's something off about the `dateadd` part. Unless I make `15` into `12`, the `patient_id` = `3` is also returned.

Comment: Ahh, just kidding. The way I defined the problem, `patient_id` = `3` _should_ be returned. Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used lag.

```
declare @Codes table
(
    diagnosis_code CHAR,
    visit_date     DATE,
    visit_id       INT,
    patient_id     int
);

insert into @Codes
values
('A',              '2018-01-01' ,1,           1)
,('B' ,             '2018-01-01', 1,           1)
,('A' ,             '2018-01-07', 2,           1)
,('C'             ,'2018-01-01', 3,           2)
/*
D              2018-01-01 4           3
D              2018-01-15 5           3
E              2018-01-01 6           4
E              2018-01-01 6           4
A              2018-01-07 7           1
*/



select *
from (
select *
    --,rn=row_number() over (partition by patient_ID,diagnosis_code order by visit_date)
    ,DaysSince = datediff(day,lag(visit_date,1) over (partition by patient_ID,diagnosis_code order by visit_date),visit_date) 
from @Codes
) a
where a.DaysSince<=15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inbuilt `FIRST_VALUE` and `DATEADD` functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT patient_id,diagnosis_code 
FROM
(SELECT 
    FIRST_VALUE(visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id,diagnosis_code ORDER BY visit_id ASC) AS Initial_Visit,
    DATEADD(DAY,15,first_value(visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id,diagnosis_code ORDER BY visit_id ASC)) Window
    ,* FROM Codes
)m
 WHERE 
    Initial_Visit <> visit_date
    AND visit_date <= Window
```